# I use sqldependency AND signalR AND thread but it goes on infinite loop

Tags: multithreading, loops, signalr, infinite, sqldependency

I use sqldependency AND signalR AND thread but it goes on infinite loop 
combine BackgroundWorker in global.aspx and sqldependency and signalR
I dont know about problem  please help me.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    //if (session != null && HttpContext.Current != null)
    //{
    try
    {
        CSASPNETBackgroundWorker.BackgroundWorker worker = new CSASPNETBackgroundWorker.BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new CSASPNETBackgroundWorker.BackgroundWorker.DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorker(null);

        // This Background Worker is Applicatoin Level,
        // so it will keep working and it is shared by all users.
        Application["worker"] = worker;
        // Code that runs on application startup 
    }
    catch { }
    // }
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(connectionstring);
}
```

string user_id;

```
void worker_DoWork(ref int progress,
      ref object _result, params object[] arguments)
{
    // Do the operation every 1 second wihout the end.
    while (true)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randnum = rand.Next(5000, 20000);
        Thread.Sleep(randnum);
        // This statement will run every 1 second.
       // string user_id = "";
       // if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
           // user_id = "22";// HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString();
            user_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["session_user_id"].ToString();
            updatealarm(user_id);
        }
        // Other logic which you want it to keep running.
        // You can do some scheduled tasks here by checking DateTime.Now.
    }
}
```

AND

public class AlarmInfoRepository {
     string connectionstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["officeConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     public IEnumerable GetData(string user_id)
     {

```
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
     {
         //PersianCalendar jc = new PersianCalendar();
         //string todayStr = jc.GetYear(DateTime.Now).ToString("0000") + "/" + jc.GetMonth(DateTime.Now).ToString("00") + "/" +
         //    jc.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now).ToString("00");
         //string timeStr = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", jc.GetHour(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)), jc.GetMinute(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)), jc.GetSecond(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)));

         if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
             connection.Open(); 
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[id],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].peygir_id,dbo.[web_alarmkartable].user_id,
    dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[content],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[latestcreate_date],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[latestcreate_time], 
    dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[firstcreate_date],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[firstcreate_time],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[duration],
    dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[periodtype_id],dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[period],ISNULL(dbo.[web_alarmkartable].[color],'') AS color,dbo.[web_alarmkartable].id_tel FROM dbo.[web_alarmkartable] where dbo.[web_alarmkartable].content !=''  AND dbo.[web_alarmkartable].content IS NOT NULL 
    AND (dbo.[web_alarmkartable].seen IS NULL OR dbo.[web_alarmkartable].seen =0) AND (dbo.[web_alarmkartable].expier IS NULL OR dbo.[web_alarmkartable].expier =0 ) 
    AND (dbo.[web_alarmkartable].del=0 OR dbo.[web_alarmkartable].del IS NULL) AND dbo.[web_alarmkartable].user_id=" + user_id, connection))
         {
             // Make sure the command object does not already have
             // a notification object associated with it.
             command.Notification = null;
             SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
             dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

             using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                 return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                     .Select(x => new AlarmInfo()
                     {
                         id = x.GetInt32(0),
                         peygir_id = x.GetInt32(1),
                         user_id = x.GetInt32(2),
                         content = x.GetString(3),
                         latestcreate_date = x.GetString(4),
                         latestcreate_time = x.GetString(5),
                         firstcreate_date = x.GetString(6),
                         firstcreate_time = x.GetString(7),
                         duration = x.GetDecimal(8),
                         periodtype_id = x.GetInt32(9),
                         period = x.GetDecimal(10),
                         color = x.GetString(11),
                         id_tel = x.GetInt32(12)
                     }).ToList();

         }
         //if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
         //    connection.Close(); 
     }
 }


private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.Info.ToString() == "Insert" || e.Info.ToString() == "Update") && e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        AlermHub.Show(e.Info.ToString());
}
```

}

AND